# Filling a buffer with a repeating pattern of N bytes

Tags: performance, algorithm, c

My program will clear the screen to a 24bit RGB color; in other words, it will fill a buffer with a repeating pattern of 3 bytes. So I wrote patternMemcpy to perform this operation efficiently*. It works by doubling the size of each memcpy.

```c
// Fills a buffer with a repeating pattern of N bytes
int patternMemcpy(uint8_t* buf, size_t bufSize, const uint8_t* PatternData, size_t PatternSize) {
    if (buf == NULL || PatternData == NULL) { return -1; }
    if (bufSize == 0 || PatternSize == 0) { return 0; } // 0 Bytes to copy
    if (bufSize <= PatternSize) {
        memcpy(buf,PatternData,bufSize);
        return 0;
    }
    memcpy(buf,PatternData,PatternSize); // Initial Copy
    size_t len = PatternSize;
    size_t pos = PatternSize;
    
    while (pos + len <= bufSize) {
        memcpy(buf + pos,buf,len); 
        pos += len;
        len *= 2; // Doubles copy size each iteration
    }
    memcpy(buf + pos,buf,bufSize - len); // Copies the remaining portion
    return 0;
}
```

Below is an alternate version, which assumes that the pattern is already written at the beginning of the buffer.

```c
// Assumes the pattern is set in the first N bytes in buf
int inPlacePatternMemcpy(uint8_t* buf, size_t bufSize, size_t PatternSize) {
    if (buf == NULL) { return -1; }
    if (bufSize == 0 || PatternSize == 0) { return 0; } // 0 Bytes to copy
    if (bufSize <= PatternSize) { return 0; }
    size_t len = PatternSize;
    size_t pos = PatternSize;

    while (pos + len <= bufSize) {
        memcpy(buf + pos,buf,len); 
        pos += len;
        len *= 2; // Doubles copy size each iteration
    }
    memcpy(buf + pos,buf,bufSize - len); // Copies the remaining portion
    return 0;
}
```

Any recommendations or suggestions you would make for either function? I did notice that the code seems to use `msvcrt!memmove` instead of `msvcrt!memcpy`, even though there shouldn't be any pointer overlap. Should I try to change it to use memcpy instead of memmove? (MSYS2, MinGW64, gcc -O3)

*I tested a few methods and "Binary Memcpy" method was the fastest, which is what I implemented above. Each method filled a ~24.9mb array with a 3 byte pattern [(Method Comparison Graph)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gln0d.png).

Answer (score 9):

#### Function-Call Conventions

C99 and above allow you to write `bufSize` as a function parameter, then `buffer[bufSize]`, to help the compiler with static analysis.  MSVC, however, doesn’t support this.

It is also a good idea to make function parameters `const` (if pointers, `* const`) unless you need to modify the arguments themselves (not memory they reference).

You shouldn’t return a meaningless value.  It’s bad practice not to check the return value for errors.  A meaningless return value leads to that.  The only errors you check for are logic errors that you abort on.

#### There is One Bug

You have the line

```
while (pos + len <= bufSize)
```

This could wrap around, causing an infinite loop.

### A Better Algorithm

What you want for fast performance is to generate vector instructions.  Since the pattern repeats, you want to store the repeating pattern in vector registers, and move that.  On a machine where those are 32 bytes (256 bits) wide, this means you should create an aligned buffer the size of the least common multiple of the vector size (32 bytes) and the pattern size (3 bytes), which is 96 bytes.

The compiler will be able to optimize copies from this buffer to use vector instructions.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#if (__x86_64__ || _M_X64) && __AVX2__
#  define VECTOR_ALIGNMENT 32U
#else
#  define VECTOR_ALIGNMENT alignof(max_align_t)
#endif

void patternFill(const size_t n, uint8_t dest[n], const uint8_t pattern[3]) {
    assert(dest);
    assert(pattern);

    const alignas(VECTOR_ALIGNMENT) uint8_t src[96] = {
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
    };

    assert(n + sizeof(src) - 1U > n);

    size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i + sizeof(src) <= n; i += sizeof(src)) {
        memcpy(dest+i, src, sizeof(src));
    }

    memcpy(dest+i, src, n-i);
}
```

Clang 18.1.0 with `-std=c17 -march=x86-64-v3 -O3` compiles the critical loop to:

```
.LBB0_5:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovdqa ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsp]
        vmovdqa ymm1, ymmword ptr [rsp + 32]
        vmovdqa ymm2, ymmword ptr [rsp + 64]
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 64], ymm2
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 32], ymm1
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax], ymm0
        lea     rcx, [rax + 96]
        add     rax, 192
        cmp     rax, rdx
        mov     rax, rcx
        jbe     .LBB0_5
```

Which loads 96 bytes from the top of the stack (which will be hot in the cache) into vector registers, and stores them into the destination buffer.  With an alignment of 32 bytes, the compiler slightly optimizes to load with `vmovdqa` rather than `vmovdqu` instructions.

GCC 13.2 instead keeps the source bytes in six 16-bit vector registers between iterations of the loop:

```
.L3:
        vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rdi-96+rax], xmm5
        mov     rdx, rax
        vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rdi-80+rax], xmm4
        vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rdi-64+rax], xmm3
        vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rdi-48+rax], xmm2
        vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rdi-32+rax], xmm1
        vmovdqu XMMWORD PTR [rdi-16+rax], xmm0
        add     rax, 96
        cmp     rcx, rax
        jnb     .L3
```

#### Optimizing Further with Compiler Extensions

GCC, Clang and ICX all have extensions that allow you to tell the compiler that a pointer or index is aligned.  If you can make the assumption that your destination buffer is aligned to the size of your vectors, you can use them to enable some small optimizations:

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#if (__x86_64__ || _M_X64) && __AVX2__
#  define VECTOR_ALIGNMENT 32U
#else
#  define VECTOR_ALIGNMENT alignof(max_align_t)
#endif

#if __clang__ | __INTEL_LLVM__COMPILER
#  define ASSUME(p) __builtin_assume(p)
#  define V_ALIGNED_PTR(p) __builtin_align_up((p), VECTOR_ALIGNMENT)
  typedef __attribute__((align_value(VECTOR_ALIGNMENT))) uint8_t* ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR;
#elif __GNUC__
#  define ASSUME(p) __attribute((__assume__(p)))
#  define V_ALIGNED_PTR(p) __builtin_assume_aligned((p), VECTOR_ALIGNMENT)
  typedef __attribute__((aligned(VECTOR_ALIGNMENT))) uint8_t* ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR;
#else
#  define ASSUME(p) /* will be [[assume(p)]] in C23. */
#  define V_ALIGNED_PTR(p) (p)
  typedef uint8_t* ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR;
#endif

void patternFill3(const size_t n, ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR restrict dest, const uint8_t pattern[3]) {
    assert(dest);
    assert(pattern);

    ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR const dest_aligned = V_ALIGNED_PTR(dest);

    const alignas(VECTOR_ALIGNMENT) uint8_t src[96] = {
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
    };

    static_assert( sizeof(src) % VECTOR_ALIGNMENT == 0 &&
                     sizeof(src) % 3 == 0,
                   "");

    assert(n + sizeof(src) - 1U > n);

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i + sizeof(src) <= n; i += sizeof(src)) {
        ASSUME(i%VECTOR_ALIGNMENT == 0);
        memcpy(dest_aligned+i, src, sizeof(src));
    }

    ASSUME(i%VECTOR_ALIGNMENT == 0);
    memcpy(dest_aligned+i, src, n-i);
}
```

C23 will simplify this a bit, notably by making `alignas` a keyword and adding an `[[assume(predicate)]];` statement, but support is not there yet.

This version will optimize the unaligned-vector-move instructions to aligned-vector-move on both GCC and Clang.  This small change to the code likely won’t make a huge difference,but aligning all your buffers optimally likely will.  It is crucial that, if you use it, you only call the function on a properly-aligned destination buffer!

If you declare the function `static`, the compiler further optimizes by ignoring the calling convention.  It might be able to get the same optimizations from whole-program optimization (`-flto`).  GCC now uses `vmovdqa` within the inner loop.  Clang now unrolls the loop, setting three 32-byte registers and then executing a series of `vmovaps` instructions that store those three registers over and over.  ICX 2024 recognizes that there is a 24-byte repeating pattern, and shortens the inner loop to:

```
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovups xmmword ptr [rax + buffer+4032], xmm0 # AlignMOV convert to UnAlignMOV 
        mov     qword ptr [rax + buffer+4048], rcx
        add     rax, 24
        jne     .LBB0_1
```

Which sets a 16-byte register followed by an 8-byte register.

#### Compatibility with Microsoft C

Since Microsoft has never fully supported C99, and has its own incompatible extensions, the code above would need a little tweaking to work on MSVC 19.

```c
#include <assert.h>
// #include <stdalign.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#if (__x86_64__ || _M_X64) && __AVX2__
#  define VECTOR_ALIGNMENT 32U
#else
#  define VECTOR_ALIGNMENT alignof(max_align_t)
#endif

#if _MSC_VER
#  define ASSUME(p) __assume(p)
  typedef __declspec(align(VECTOR_ALIGNMENT)) uint8_t* ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR;
#  define V_ALIGNED_PTR(p) ((__declspec(align(VECTOR_ALIGNMENT)) void*)(p))
#elif __clang__ | __INTEL_LLVM__COMPILER
#  define ASSUME(p) __builtin_assume(p)
  typedef __attribute__((align_value(VECTOR_ALIGNMENT))) uint8_t* ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR;
#  define V_ALIGNED_PTR(p) ((ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR)(p))
#elif __GNUC__
#  define ASSUME(p) __attribute((__assume__(p)))
#  define V_ALIGNED_PTR(p) __builtin_assume_aligned((p), VECTOR_ALIGNMENT)
  typedef __attribute__((aligned(VECTOR_ALIGNMENT))) uint8_t* ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR;
#else
#  define ASSUME(p) /* will be [[assume(p)]] in C23. */
#  define V_ALIGNED_PTR(p) (p)
  typedef uint8_t* ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR;
#endif

void patternFill3(const size_t n, ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR restrict dest, const uint8_t pattern[3]) {
    assert(dest);
    assert(pattern);

    ALIGNED_BYTE_PTR const dest_aligned = V_ALIGNED_PTR(dest);

    const _Alignas(VECTOR_ALIGNMENT) uint8_t src[96] = {
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
        pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2], pattern[0], pattern[1], pattern[2],
    };

    static_assert( sizeof(src) % VECTOR_ALIGNMENT == 0 &&
                     sizeof(src) % 3 == 0,
                   "");

    assert(n + sizeof(src) - 1U > n);

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i + sizeof(src) <= n; i += sizeof(src)) {
        ASSUME(i%VECTOR_ALIGNMENT == 0);
        memcpy(dest_aligned+i, src, sizeof(src));
    }

    ASSUME(i%VECTOR_ALIGNMENT == 0);
    memcpy(dest_aligned+i, src, n-i);
}
```

On MSVC 19.38 with `/std:c17 /utf-8 /arch:AVX2 /Zc:__STDC__ /O2 /EHsc  /Wall /external:anglebrackets /external:W0`, the inner loop compiles to:

```
$LL4@patternFil:
        vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax-96], ymm2
        vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax-64], ymm1
        vmovups YMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax-32], ymm0
        add     rax, 96                             ; 00000060H
        add     rcx, 96                             ; 00000060H
        cmp     rax, rbx
        jbe     SHORT $LL4@patternFil
```

This is better than the other compilers, overall: it stores the buffer in three AVX registers and copies those to memory without reloading them.  It does not use aligned move instructions, but most CPUs already do a good job with unaligned move instructions on aligned data.

#### Test Your Code

And a basic test driver to check correctness:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

uint8_t buffer[4096];

int main(void) {
    static const uint8_t pattern[3] = {1, 2, 3};

    patternFill(sizeof(buffer), buffer, pattern);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); ++i) {
        if (buffer[i] != i%3 + 1) {
            fflush(stdout);
            fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected value %u at position %zu.\n", (unsigned)buffer[i], i);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    printf("Fill verified.");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Code on [Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/nznh5xbjE)

#### That Doesn’t Meet the Requirements

This assumes a three-byte pattern, but it would be possible to calculate the least common multiple of the pattern size and the architecture’s vector size at runtime, fill that many bytes of the destination buffer, and then fill the rest of the buffer with copies of that.

Comment: Making parameter reference types value-const is very important, but making other parameter types const is just clutter. The most important thing a function signature does is define a contract, and the latter kind of const does not add to the contract.

Comment: @Reinderien This might be true in a function *prototype*. However, in a function *definition*, declaring the arguments `const` protects you from modifying them accidentally. It has the same benefits as declaring any other variable `const`.

Comment: ... That's often clutter too, if overused.

Comment: @Reinderien I personally consider it best practice to declare `const` wherever possible. But this is why Rust makes it the default, and requires programmers to add `mut` if they need it. The compiler even warns if you didn’t need `mut`.

Comment: I do not believe C2X has `[[assume(predicate)]]`, or at least cppreference doesn't report it. Perhaps you meant [C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes)?

Comment: @Harith Either that’s what I said, or I made a typo, edited it out, and forgot about it. Either way, you’re right: `[[assume(predicate)]]` was introduced in C23.

Answer (score 6):

- Use `restrict` to indicate the 2 buffers should not overlap.  Or better, use `memmove()` for first copy to negate `restrict` need.
- Once the buffer size is large, on `memcpy()` can be assumed to be quite efficient - employing "tricks" that make sense on the target platform.  So I do not suggest trying to out-think how to best call that function.
- View `PatternSize == 0` as an error.
- Consider `void` vs `uint8_t`.  There really is no type matching needed and `uint8_t` is an *optional* type.
- Return something more useful the -1, 0.  Maybe the pointer to the end/start of the copy (or `NULL` on any failure).
- Avoid overflow in addition and multiplication.

Putting these ideas together into some illustrative code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Fills a buffer with a repeating pattern of N bytes
void* patternMemcpy(size_t bufSize, void *buf, //
      size_t PatternSize, const void *PatternData) {
  if (buf == NULL || PatternData == NULL || PatternSize == 0) {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (bufSize < PatternSize) {
    if (bufSize == 0) {
      return buf;
    }
    PatternSize = bufSize;
  }
  memmove(buf, PatternData, PatternSize); // This allows removal of restrict.
  size_t len = PatternSize;
  size_t pos = PatternSize;

  while (len <= bufSize - pos) {
    memcpy((unsigned char*) buf + pos, buf, len);
    pos += len;
    len = len < SIZE_MAX / 2 ? len * 2 : SIZE_MAX;
  }
  memcpy((unsigned char*) buf + pos, buf, bufSize - len); // Copies the remaining portion
  return buf;
}
```

Comment: @Reinderien  Any particular item you would like expanded?

Comment: @Reinderien Yes I was concerned about `len * ` overflowing and decided it was possible, so re-wrote as `len < SIZE_MAX / 2 ? len * 2 : SIZE_MAX`.  Stray ending text removed.